# How to decide what kind of resolutions should we use to calculate Ext and Tor?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology, homological-algebra

In general, when we calculate groups like Ext and Tor, how should we choose between free, projective and injective resolutions?

For example, why does Hatcher 3.1 only consider free resolution but not the other two? Is this simply because we can find free resolutions for abelian groups?

Comment: When we consider abelian groups, free is equivalent to projective since $\mathbb{Z}$ is a PID

Comment: Projective resolutions are "dual" to injective resolutions, so we are often "free" to use both. So the answer to the title question probably is: "We decide by convenience".

Comment: You'll probably find this [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/342534/90543) helpful.